# Preventing the List of Figures from Adopting the Display Style of Captions

Tags: table-of-contents, captions, lists

Consider the code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx,caption}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Allows one to make bold smallcaps.

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
  \includegraphics[width=.75\linewidth,angle=0]{example-image}
  \captionsetup{labelformat=empty} \vspace{10pt}
    \caption{\textbf{\scshape{\LARGE Image Caption}}}
  \label{fig:Image Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
  \includegraphics[width=.75\linewidth,angle=0]{example-image-a}
  \captionsetup{labelformat=empty} \vspace{10pt}
    \caption{\textbf{\scshape{\small Image Caption-A}}}
  \label{fig:Image Caption-A}
\end{figure}

\listoffigures
\end{document}
```

which produces the following two captioned figures and *List of Figures*---

[image]

[image]

[image]

Notice that each item in the *List of Figures* reflects respective caption styles.

QUESTION: How may I get the items in the *List of Figures* to be displayed in, say, the default font---instead of adopting the style of each caption?

Thank you.

Comment: \caption already has an optional argument for the LOF entry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't the greatest answer but will post it either way in case it is useful to others in the future:

[image]

[image]

It essentially just revolves around wrapping the `\caption` command in another command. I am not sure how to parse the input to strip out the command sequence i.e. `\small`, `\Large` hence the second argument but there is probably a better way to do this.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx,caption}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Allows one to make bold smallcaps.

\newcommand\CaptionC[2]{\caption[#1]{\textbf{\scshape{#2 #1}}}}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
  \includegraphics[width=.75\linewidth,angle=0]{example-image}
  \captionsetup{labelformat=empty} \vspace{10pt}
    \CaptionC{Image Caption}{\Large}
  \label{fig:Image Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
  \includegraphics[width=.75\linewidth,angle=0]{example-image-a}
  \captionsetup{labelformat=empty} \vspace{10pt}
    \CaptionC{Image Caption-A}{\small}
  \label{fig:Image Caption-A}
\end{figure}

\listoffigures
\end{document}
```